abinitio splitting data into two columns, extracting data
I have a file like this :
grid     all_cells
123      ARHAR47L_0.4667,ARHAR44L_0.2667,ARHAR43L_0.7788

I would like to split all_cells columns into two columns like below.
How can I achieve that ?
grid cell     ratio
123  ARHAR47L 0.4667
123  ARHAR44L 0.2667
123  ARHAR43L 0.7788

Firstly I splitted the all_cells column by comma . The result is a vector
out.cell_ratio:: string_split(in.all_cells,",");
grid    cell_ratio  
123     ARHAR47L_0.4667
        ARHAR44L_0.2667
        ARHAR43L_0.7788
        

Then I used normalize component to extract cell and ratio. Now I have both cell and ratio columns. What I want is to extract cell and ratio and assign them to cell and ratio columns.
out :: length(in) =

    begin
      out::length_of(in.cell_ratio);
    end;
    
    out :: normalize(in, index) =
    begin
      out.* :: in.*;
      out.cell :: in.cell_ratio[index];
      out.ratio:: in.cell_ratio[index];
    end;


I solved the problem by Normalize and Reformat components.
